# Visual studio 2008 ignoring ajax calls in load test results

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2008, load-testing

In visual studio 2008 load tests can I collect averages only for other than ajax calls (ones that don't have x-microsoftajax: Delta=true header)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. There are two solutions I was able to apply so far:

1. Put ajax calls into dependent requests. This results in page time is calculated by summing initial page load time and all ajax requests (and other dependent requests)
2. Setting "Record Results"to False on Ajax request in web test. This will result in these page calls will be ignored when calculating page average response time, but will still be used when calculating average request response time.
3. This will probably be the right solution. One can use transactions to group requests. Just right click on web test rood node and select "Add transaction"

Maybe there are other ides. I would like to hear more suggestions, because I fill like still missing something.